# MySQL query using IN based on UNION fails with number of columns

Tags: mysql

In MySQL i have the following statement which will not run as the columns are not the same, i do not see why my where and in statement have to have same columns.

```
SELECT 
  keyArchive,
  RelPath,
  ToSummary,
  Sender 
FROM
  tblarchive 
WHERE keyArchive IN 
  (SELECT 
    keyarchive 
  FROM
    tblarchive 
  WHERE (
      MATCH(SenderEmail) AGAINST ('"name@company.com"')
    )) 
  UNION
  (SELECT 
    keyfarchive 
  FROM
    tblarchiverecipients 
  WHERE recipientemail = 'name@company.com')
```

If i run statement after where keyarchive in , it completes correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You Are trying to union The initial

```
SELECT 
  keyArchive,
  RelPath,
  ToSummary,
  Sender
```

query with the final SELECT query. Unions must have the same amount of columns. I suspect you meant to union the two latter queries. Try:

```
SELECT 
  keyArchive,
  RelPath,
  ToSummary,
  Sender 
FROM
  tblarchive 
WHERE keyArchive IN 
  ((SELECT 
    keyarchive 
  FROM
    tblarchive 
  WHERE (
      MATCH(SenderEmail) AGAINST ('"name@company.com"')
    )) 
  UNION
  (SELECT 
    keyfarchive 
  FROM
    tblarchiverecipients 
  WHERE recipientemail = 'name@company.com'))
```

The only addition is to wrap the `IN` clause in parenthesis.